# Infowindow don't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I'm using angularjs to develop an app.
I've used [ng-map](http://ngmap.github.io/) to create a map and use marker and infowindow. But I have a problem: when I press on marker, infowindow don't appear.
This is HTML:

```
<map>
    <marker id="foo"clickable="true" zIndex="1" shape="{{shape}}" on-click="showInfoWindow(event, 'bar')" icon="{{image}}" position="current-position"></marker>
    <info-window id="bar" visible-on-marker="foo">
       Hi, I'm InfoWindow
           </info-window>
</map>
```

My .js:

```
$scope.image = {
    url: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png',
    size: [20, 32],
    origin: [0,0],
    anchor: [0, 32]
    };

    $scope.shape = {
                coords: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18 , 1],
                type: 'poly'
              };
```

Anyone can help me?

***EDIT:***

I've tried it on android device but it doesn't work and the logcat don't show me any error. It seems the marker cannot be click... But I've tried this on browser(Google chrome) and the on click works well.

Comment: do you get a javascript error?  What does the `showInfoWindow` function look like?

Comment: From the `ngmap` doc [here](http://ngmap.github.io/basics.html#/map-coordinates#map-coordinates), you just need to do `<info-window id="1" position="41.850033,-87.6500523" visible="true">
      <div ng-non-bindable=""> CONTENTS</div>
    </info-window> `

Comment: @duncan showInfoWindow is a function of ng-map. You can see an example here http://ngmap.github.io/drawings.html#/infowindow-simple-max#infowindow-simple-max

Comment: @bjiang I have an array that contain multiple marker. So with ng-repeat, I put the marker on map, and I would like that when I click on a marker, appear an infowindow. When the map is create, infowindow have not to appear, but when I press on a marker infowindow have to appear.

Comment: @bjiang But it doesn't work even with one marker